# High number of hard page faults, low memory usage

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, performance

My Sharepoint server had 16GB of RAM, it would use 75% on average but have an average of 700-900 hard page faults per second.  I upgraded the RAM to 32GB and now it uses 25% but the average number of hard page faults per second are still at about 700/s.  Does this indicate a problem?

I thought hard page faults meant that there wasn't enough room in the RAM so the computer's using the HDD more than it should (looking to the page file for memory pages that could be stored in RAM).  I thought that putting more RAM in meant that the hard page faults per second would drop - why hasn't this happened?

Also, we have a 200 person company accessing this single Sharepoint 2010 server, is 16GB enough RAM for that server?

Comment: Add details about your farm setup.

Comment: What do you want to know? I've got 1 front-end server and 1 SQL server.  It's a pretty basic set up

Comment: On which server you have Search Configured. How large is the Content Databases? How frequent the Search Crawls are running? Can you disable the Crawl and check if that brings down the Page Faults.

Comment: Content database is about 600GB and crawls run every day. The crawl for today is almost done so I'll check to see if the faults go down